# Как передать результат динамического запроса в переменную?

Tags: sql, plsql

Наверное, частый вопрос, но баянометр не показал похожих.
Есть динамический запрос, который возвращает одно значение. Нужно сохранить его в переменную. Как это сделать, ведь внешние переменные не видны в нем? Например:

```
declare
  str1 varchar2(100);
  str2 varchar2(10) := 'dual';
begin
  execute immediate 'SELECT ''Нужно больше золота'' into str1 from '|| str2;
end;
```

Очевидно, в str1 не попадет нужное значение. Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быть такого не может, чтобы этот вопрос не был баяном. А вы чуть-чуть до правильного ответа недотянули:

```
declare
  str1 varchar2(100);
  str2 varchar2(10) := 'dual';
begin
  execute immediate 'SELECT ''Нужно больше золота'' from '|| str2 into str1;
  dbms_output.put_line(str1);
end;
/
```

Небольшое пояснение. `INTO` - это ключевое слово для PL/SQL, а не для SQL. Соответственно, если вы исполняете динамический **SQL**, надо писать SQL запрос - без `INTO`. Как у меня выше. А если хотите **PL/SQL** и с `INTO`, то надо писать в `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` PL/SQL блок:

```
declare
  str1 varchar2(100);
  str2 varchar2(10) := 'dual';
begin
  execute immediate 'begin SELECT ''Нужно больше золота'' into :P from '
     || str2 || '; end;' using out str1;
  dbms_output.put_line(str1);
end;
/
```